# Transformar a entrada de DATA em uma variável PHP/JAVA

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, variáveis

Espero que entendam a situação:
Programando uma página web, criei um campo `data` onde o usuário escolhe a data que deverá **filtrar** as informações contidas no site, ou seja, mostrar apenas as informações refentes ao dia ou período escolhidos. Pois bem, como posso transformar essa entrada de data em uma variável e usá-la posteriormente no restante dos códigos, sabendo que caso o usuário não escolha uma data específica deve-se aparecer todas as informações referentes a todas as datas? Ainda não consegui pensar em uma forma de fazer isso. Busco informações de um banco de dados MYSQL.

Comment: Poderia postar o código que você implementou?

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi sua pergunta mas vamos lá. (Nos exemplos utilizei angularjs e codeigniter juntos, logo não inclui arquivos e códigos referentes a roteamento e nem a configuração)

- **Caminho da sua view até o banco e do banco até sua view**

**1. HTML**

Primeiramente você tera que pegar a informação via input em formulário HTML certo?

```
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Ano de referência teste:</label>

                                <input type="date"  ng-model="ano_teste.value"
                                       placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" class="form-control width-auto" ng-required="false"/>
                            </div>

                                <button type="submit" ng-click="enviarData(ano_teste.value);" class="btn btn-primary col-md-offset-5 col-xs-offset-5">Gerar Relatório</button>
```

**2. JS**

Posteriormente via javascript você terá que enviar essa informação que estará em json para o seu controller (*obs: supondo que você esteja utilizando MVC*), supondo que você irá tratar o formato somente na classe de controller, que seria o correto, a sua data estaria até então nesse formato: *"2010-01-01T02:00:00.000Z"*

```
  $scope.enviarData =  function enviarData(ano_teste){

        //busca dados
        var rows = [];   
        var data = { ano_teste: ano_teste };
        $http.post('get_relatorio_ano_teste', data).then(function(resposta){
            if (resposta.data.status === "error"){
                toastr["error"]('', resposta.data.message);
            }

            for (var i in resposta.data){
                rows.push({
                    c: [resposta.data[i]]
                });
            }
```

**3. Controller (PHP/JAVA)**

Em controller que você vai tratar o formato da data, colocando no padrão date do MYSQL, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

EXEMPLO:

```
public function get_relatorio_ano_teste(){
            if (!is_logged_in() || !$this->session->has_userdata('admin')){
                $message = array("status"=>"error","message"=>"Faça login novamente");
                echo json_encode ($message);
                return;
            }

            $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
            $data = json_decode($request_body);
            //valida os dados enviados
            if (!array_key_exists('ano_teste', $data) ||
                strlen(trim($data->ano_teste)) == 0 ||
                $data->ano_teste == null ){

                $data_teste = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data->ano_teste));

                $this->load->model('secretaria/relatorio/RelatorioM');
                $row = $this->RelatorioM->gerar_relatorio_generico($data_teste);
            }else{

            $data_teste = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data->ano_teste));

            $this->load->model('secretaria/relatorio/RelatorioM');
            $row = $this->RelatorioM->gerar_relatorio_com_data($data_teste);
            }
        echo json_encode ($row);
        return;
        }
```

E em seguida enviar até model para que lá se dê prosseguimento a comunicação com banco. Aqui também é onde você irá ver se o usuário utilizou o campo para filtrar alguma data ou deixou vazio, se for **null** você chama uma função do model que seleciona e retorna todas as instâncias, caso contrário você chama a função aonde a query tem um "... WHERE data = ? ..." e retorna as instâncias com a restrição de data.

**4. Model (PHP/JAVA)**

Em model você irá fazer a parte de comunicação com o banco, é aonde ficará a query e é a parte que receberia a resposta do banco e através de um return você devolveria alguma coisa conforme a sua necessidade.

```
  public function gerar_relatorio_com_data($data_teste){

        $sql = "
          SELECT *
          FROM exemplo as e 
          WHERE e.data_teste = ?
          ORDER BY e.nome
            ";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql,array($data_teste));
        $rows = $query->result();
        if (empty($rows)){
            return array("status"=>"error","message"=>"Não existem resultados pra esse período");
        }else{
            return $rows;
        }
    }
```

- **Lembrando que a utilização de padrões facilitam a vida do programador**

Alguns frameworks, bibliotecas, arquiteturas de software foram feitas para facilitar o desenvolvimento, se você está com dificuldade para modelar seu problema aconselho que pesquise um pouco sobre as ferramentas bem difundidas no mercado, além de você achar mais resultados quando for pesquisar, você vai ver que os problemas ficaram mais fáceis de modelar. Eu utilizo **codeigniter**, **angularjs**, **react**, **npm**... entre outras que facilitaram minha vida, faz pouco tempo que aprendi web, mas como estou tentando aprender já aplicando padrões as coisas ficaram um pouco mais fáceis de absorver, e o melhor que foi em um curto espaço de tempo. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Gabriel, teria como demonstrar um exemplo genérico disso tudo?

Comment: Então até posso, mas você vai utilizar algum framework especifico?

Comment: vou fazer um exemplo utilizando angular com codeigniter